# Why exactly is this syntax error happening in C++ for me..?

Tags: c++

why exactly is this happening?

```
cout << "Your choice of numbers is...?" << endl;
```

> error C2143: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before '<<'

Comment: Please post a small but complete program which triggers the error so that people don't have to guess what's going on. This makes it much more likely that you get a useful answer.

Comment: I think you should put all the source code.

Comment: Try to post a complete example that demonstrates that. With includes and other stuff. If you find it working perfectly, then look carefully before that line, maybe the real error is somewhere else, that happens sometimes.

Comment: you should post at least few lines just above this `cout`.

Answer (score 2):

Hi do you include iostream and use namespace

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: //imputing a value
int selectedNum;
cout << "Your choice of numbers is...?" << endl;
cin >> selectedNum;

Comment: @mike: Please edit your original question when providing more information. Code which is pasted into a comment is barely readable (and in this case it's not complete either).

Answer (score 0):

Missing namespace?

Try `use namespace std;` at the beginning of your code!

Answer (score -2):

I would not recommend using namespace std;

Using the fully qualified name i.e std::cout would be a better alternative

Comment: "Using namespace" is severely overused, yes, but its usage is too often considered an inferior practice, no matter, how or why do you use it. "Using namespace" is actually fine, if you only do it in the source file where you actively employ it. But not using this directive in some globally included header. Language features aren't good or bad - it's how you use them.

Comment: Quite contrary. using namespace in headers is very bad thing for sure. In implementation files using namspace saves typing, makes code more readable (shorter lines with fewer words are easier to grasp).